# Printing a reversed string/array in C

Tags: c, arrays, printf, c-strings

I'm trying to print a reversed string/array. I've used the following code and it seems to be able to give my second array, `revString`, values in the correct order from the first array `string`. I am also able to print individual characters in both arrays, and I'm able to print the entire string of the first array. However the `revString` array doesn't print at all. I'm wondering if I am missing a huge point here.

```
void reverseString(char string[]) {
    int i = strlen(string);
    int i_2 = 0;
    revString arrayet
    char revString[i + 1];
    char *character; 

    while (i > -1) {
        character = &string[i];
        revString[i_2] = *character;
        printf("%c", revString[i_2]);
        i = i - 1;
        i_2 = i_2 + 1;
    }
    revString[i_2] = '\0';
    printf("%d\n", i_2);
    printf("%s", revString);
}
```

The code gives now the following output with example string `"Hello World"`;

```
dlrow olleH13
```

As you can see the final `printf` statement doesn't do anything

Comment: I think it prints the value, but your program quits before the value shows up to the console. Add `\n` after `%s` to see the printout.

Comment: You want to double check indexing of the source string. Which elements of the source array do access during the 1st iteration?

Comment: Also you might like to read this: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: `character = &string[i]; revString[i_2] = *character;` is a very roundabout way to say `revString[i_2] = string[i];`.

Comment: the final printf statement doesn't do anything because the first character of the reversed string is ____ (fill in the blank; use your debugger if necessary).

Comment: `char revString[i + 1];` looks incorrect to me - if you need to dynamically allocate memory you should use `malloc` or `calloc` - or use `revString[100];` if 100 is long enough  (or another number ?10000)

Comment: @tom `char revString[i + 1];` is OK.  Research variable length array or VLA.

Comment: @chux - thanks - so they came in in ANSI C99, but then since C11 they are no longer a required feature, but a conditional one... many thanks for your helpful comment.

Comment: @n.m. Thanks! I think I'll get it to work now :)

Answer (score 2):

In C language indexing is 0 based. so, if you make a string of 10 length, the last character will be at index 9.

In your code, when you are assigning characters to revString, your code is trying to access string[len].

your code should be like this..

`int i = strlen(string) - 1;`

Answer (score 1):

Your code reverses the string `string` including the null terminator at `string[i]`. The resulting array starts with a null terminator, hence `printf` outputs nothing.

Here is a modified version:

```
void reverseString(char string[]) {
    int i = strlen(string);
    int i_2 = 0;
    char revString[i + 1];
    char character;

    while (i > 0) {
        i = i - 1;
        character = string[i];
        revString[i_2] = character;
        //printf("%c", revString[i_2]);
        i_2 = i_2 + 1;
    }
    revString[i_2] = '\0';
    printf("%d\n", i_2);
    printf("%s", revString);
}
```

Output:

```
11
dlrow olleH
```